# Nesting multiple btn-group and btn-group-vertical

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I need to make a grid of buttons that will look similar to numpad.

I'm using angular and bootstrap 5 in my project so I wanted to use `btn-group` and `btn-group-vertical`.

It would work well for regular button grid but I need two buttons to be bigger - "OK" and "0" (see the snippet below). I thought I could achieve that with combination of nested vertical and horizontal groups but I can see that it doesn't work on deeper nestings - the borders are not rounding correctly.

Does the nesting work only for one level? If so, is there a way to create such numpad other than bootstrap's rows and columns with lots of css? Or maybe there's another way to include larger "OK" and "0" buttons in such grid?

Here's what I came up with so far:

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
.btn {
  height: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
}

.zero {
  width: calc(100%*2/3)
}

.decimal {
  width: 33.4%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="btn-group w-100 keys">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical w-100" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">3</button>
            <button type="butoon" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100"><i class="bi bi-backspace"></i></button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">4</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">5</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">6</button>
            <button type="butoon" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">C</button>
          </div>

          <div class="btn-group">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical w-75">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">9</button>
              </div>

              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary zero">0</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary decimal">,</button>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="btn-group-vertical w-25">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary h-100">OK</button>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved your desired result with a dummy-div-element and positioning and altering the height of the enter-key-element:

```css
:root {
    --height: 75px;
}

.btn {
    height: var(--height);
    min-height: var(--height);
    width: 25%;
}
.enter {
    position: relative;
    top: calc((var(--height) - var(--bs-border-width)) * -1);
    height: calc(var(--height) * 2 - var(--bs-border-width));
    min-height: calc(var(--height) * 2 - var(--bs-border-width));
    margin-left: calc(var(--bs-border-width) * -1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical w-100 keys">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">3</button>
            <button type="butoon" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="bi bi-backspace"></i></button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">4</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">5</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">6</button>
            <button type="butoon" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">C</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">7</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">8</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-end-0">9</button>
            <div class="w-25"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-50">0</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">,</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary enter">OK</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've used a css-var to keep the height (and the depending calculations) adjustable.